# How to use CDAP http plugin to get google cloud api with OAUTH 2.0?

Tags: google-oauth, fusion, cdap

I want to get BigQuery schema form Google Cloud API, I config all the things in GCP,and I can get info from the postman, but how to config in CDAP, here is my config:
[image]

And my CDAP version is 6.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about the oAuth documentation from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

And for the scope of the oAuth for BigQuery, you can refer to the following documentation:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#bigquery